# structure of ideals in formal power series

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals, formal-power-series

Let be $R$ a commutative unitary ring. If $R$ is a field then the ideals of $R[[t]]$ are only the ideals generated by $t^{n}$. If $R$ is not a field, but for example a $\mathbb{C}$ algebra?

Comment: If $R$ is a ring with identity you that has nontrivial ideals you get extra ideals in $R[[t]]$. For instance, if $I$ is a proper ideal of $R$, the set $I[[t]]$ of power series with coefficients in $I$ is an ideal of $R[[t]]$. In this same vein, if $I = (a)$ is a (two-sided) principal ideal of $R$, $I = (a, t^n)$ is a non-trivial ideal of $R[[t]]$ as well for each $n \geq 1$.